# MySQL date formats - difficulty querying on a date

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I want to perform a simple query like this in my PHP,

```
SELECT noslots FROM calender WHERE coursedate = '01-01-2012';
```

however my dates are stored in the database in the standard YYYY-MM-DD format so obviously I get no reults.

I have tried reading through the manual but for a beginner it is difficult to extract the correct information

thank you for any help you can offer!

[=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -

```
SELECT noslots
FROM calender
WHERE coursedate = STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

You might need to switch the %d and %m around depending on your date format.

Comment: fantastic. comment earlier got me worried.. thank you very much

Comment: If this date is user input you should make sure it is properly sanitised before being passed into the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's ONLY supported date/time format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. You cannot pass any other string and have it properly parsed as a date. It is up to you to properly format your dates into the mysql format, meaning you'll have to pass `2012-01-01` in the query.

Comment: so is there no way (like in oracle using TO_DATE) to change it as I am querying it?

Comment: You could, but doing string manipulations in SQL of data you've brought in from the outside is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP's `date()` and `strtotime()` functions:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `noslots` FROM `calender` WHERE `coursedate` = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('01-01-2012')) . "'");
```